# Size of Background image in Flash

Tags: flash, size

I have a swf and the background image looks bad in a monitor `1680 x 1050` , it get cut,

- To define this in flash, I hace to edit my image to this size `1680 x 1050`, but in flash How would I define this?. Can it be done in html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to edit your image in flash, right click-> properties->smooth